# Is Joshua an Islamic name?

Tags: names

I'm looking for a name that is English and Arabic and is has meaning in Islam.

Is this a name relevant to Islam or more towards Judaism and Christianity?

Comment: for male or female?

Comment: See [Joshua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua) in wikipedia. It seems it best fits with Christianity.

Comment: Haris is a good one and it is said the same way in both languages.

Answer (score 4):

**Joshua** is the modern English version of Hebrew name **Yehoshuah** which means *Yahweh is salvation*. **Jesus** is also a variation upon Yehoshuah and it simply is a Greek transliteration of Yehoshuah via Latin. (Source: Wikipedia)

*There is nothing un-Islamic or even Islamic about the name Joshua.* If one wants to take up this name, he can. The only recommendation one should heed IMHO is that *name should have a good meaning*.

Contrary to the widely held concept, there is no basis for labeling a name as Islamic or non-Islamic. What we generally term as Islamic names are simply *Arabic* or *Arabic versions* of the names. In most European languages the letter **J** is still pronounced as **Y**. Even in Urdu we call Jesus as **Yesu (Masih)**. Isa is simply an Arabic version of Jesus.

Jesus (Christ) – Yesu (Masih) – Isa (Masih)

Some variations of the Hebrew names that people use all over the world.

- Jakob – Jacob – Yaqoob
- Elijas – Aylia – Illyas
- Joseph – Yusuf
- Jonas – Jonah – Yunus
- John – Johannes – Johennsen - Johan – Yahya
- Markus – Mark – Marqas
- Peter – Pitrus
- Solomon – Suleiman
- David – Dawood
- Abraham – Ibrahim
- Issac – Ishaq
- Michael – Mishael – Mikhail – Mikaeel
- Gabriel – Jibraeel
- Rafael – Israpheel

Comment: Abdul-Uzza, Abdul-Laat, Raam Daas (i.e. Abdul-Raam)) are all un-Islamic names. When you say **name should have a good meaning** you cannot then say **there is no basis for labeling a name**

Comment: A name with good meaning is not just valid for so called Islamic names but names all over the world. You have used the word **Abdul** with the above names to give them a deliberate meaning. If we break the name Abdul-Uzza, it becomes _abd_ **al - Uzza**. Usage of **al** makes Uzza a specific one, i.e., the goddess of Meccan. Yes. Now it doesn't convey a good meaning.

Comment: The word **Uzza** itself has biblical/hebrew origin. It means _strength_. In Urdu we have a synonymous name _Qawi_. If there is nothing wrong with Qawi, why should there be a problem with Uzza?

Comment: Lets take a counter example. **Rahman** is a so called Islamic name. How about naming a child  **_ar_-Rahman**? Would that be okay? Or does it have an inappropriate meaning?

Answer (score 2):

*Joshua* is the English rendering of the Arabic *Yusha*, which is known as the name of the first prophet after Moses (puh) - Yusha bin Nun (puh), under whose preaching and commands Bani-Israel eventually conquered the land. All prophetic names are automatically Islamic and this is because according to Quran there has only been one religion of God and therefore all prophets were prophets of Islam.

From a cultural aspect, the Arabic *Yusha* will have more acceptability among the Muslims as compared to *Joshua*, which is perceived as Western or Christian among other possibilities.

In normal usage, to say that something is Islamic is to speak of its acceptability in the Muslim sphere, often also construed as the inverse of un-Islamic. For example, Abdul-Laat is an un-Islamic name. Taken this way, since *Joshua* is not "un-Islamic," it is Islamic.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a name relevant to Islam or more towards Judaism and Christianity?

Yes, it's relevant to Islam but the word is more towards the Judaism or Christianity.

Answer (score 0):

The Arabic name for Joshua is Yusha - from Yusha Ibn Noon who was the friend and deciple of Musa (Moses)  peace be upon him. So yes it is a muslim name

Answer (score -2):

No Joshua is not an islamic name.